# Email Notification for specific member group

Tags: members, registration

I have never used EE before this project, and I am getting used to it.  So far I like it.  I have taken the project through completion, yet now I am having a hiccup.

A client wants to have an email notification of a new member, but for specific member groups, they would like it to go to different email addresses.

For example, I have used two different forms from Simple Registration plugin to have two different groups.  Vendors and then Supporters.

When supporters register, a notification should go to one email address, where when a vendor registers the client wants it to go to a different email, as these two are handled by two different people.

Also, is there a way to control that email notification?  I have custom membership fields, and when someone registers it does not show any of my custom membership fields in the email notification to myself upon new sign up.

Sorry if I am not explaining well enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use this free addon:

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-notify-control

This allows you to create different triggers for notification. You can set one for member registration, and actually pick which member groups trigger that notification. Just make one notification for vendors, and one for supporters. Tada!

**Edit**

Here is a **functioning** example from a live application I have in the wild. When a "Records Custodians" member registers, it sends an email (it uses a message template, last field). You would just need two of these rules, one with your Supporters member group selected, one with your Vendor member group selected.

[image: MX Notify Example]

Are you sure your **email settings** are correct for this ExpressionEngine install? Go this Control Panel spot:

`Your site -> CP Home -> Tools -> Communicate`

And fire off a test email.

This addon is working on a very important application I've developed. (I redacted the name of the University I work at).

Comment: THANK YOU! I will look into this!! I couldn't find anything in my hours of searching.

Will this help me choose the member fields that send upon registration?  Currently none of my custom ones send.

Comment: ... it is **supposed** to, I believe. It might take you a minute to familiarize yourself with addon installation, but it's honestly worth it to just install it and play around.

Comment: I have been fiddling with it for a few hours now, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to set a trigger for a member group.

I don't think this is a feature through it - I can see how to send when any user registers, but I need specific member groups.  I'll keep looking and fiddling with this however!

Comment: I posted an example configuration and updated my answer. It works perfectly for me with there is a new "Records Custodians" member registered.

Comment: OH! Maybe I misunderstood? To me Send to Member Groups made me think if a new Supporter is registered, it will send to all other Supporters who registered.

Comment: My example sends an email to the newly registered user, but you could easily make the send to address supporter-registration@yourdomain.com and vendor-registration@yourdomain.com, instead of {mbr_email}.

Comment: THIS ABSOLUTELY WORKS!  THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind selecting my answer as correct? (Check mark)

Comment: I tried exactly what you have and have selected Member Validation as my trigger but only for a specific member group. However, when a different member group (or any member group) validates their email, MX Notify Control seems to get triggered. Thoughts?